# Unable to run-android on react-native when to project has react-native-reanimated on MacOs

Tags: react-native, macos, gradle, react-native-reanimated

I am creating a project that using react-native-reanimated as one of its component. But when I installed reanimated and run-android the project, An error appears as below.

```
run-android
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.1.1
Gradle: 8.3

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> [CXX1101] NDK at /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 29s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> [CXX1101] NDK at /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 29s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Does anyone has an idea to fix it? is it related to gradle version? If yes, also can you guys maybe give me some clue how to fix it. Thanks before.

And By the way, I am on Mac Os, using React-native 0.73 with jdk 17

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to set the build. gradle file

{

```
android {
ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
compileSdk 34
namespace "com.myproj"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myproj"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
....
}

after setting this you have to run this command
```

**yarn add react-native-reanimated@latest**

```
It works for me! I hope it works for you also
```